# Docusign API: Setting Tabs That Include CSS Inline in HTML document -

Tags: docusignapi

I have read that we can include CSS inline in HTML document since external CSS files are not supported (documentation link): https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/
However, do I need to convert Inline CSS vs toplevel/bottomlevel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the link you added clearly says:

> Only inline HTML styles will be reflected in the processed document.
> Any styles defined outside the page, such as tag elements or CSS, will
> not be applied.

Any links to CSS files will be ignored as well as other forms of non-inline. You must have your CSS inline as part of the HTML elements you want.